# Как использовать строку в JS c одинарными и двойными кавычками?

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs

Есть строка:

```
string organizationNameRu = "ТОВАРИЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ \"T'N'T Company\"";
```

Мне нужно строку передать в JS метод:

```
var getName = new Button
{
    ID = "btnOrganization",
    Icon = Icon.Info,
    Handler = string.Format(@"Msg.Show(message:`{1}`)",organizationNameRu} )
};
```

cейчас в JS-е получаю такую ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'N'

Как можно передать строку где имеется одинарные и двойные кавычки?

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать одинарные кавычки в этой строке через `.Replace`, что-то типа `.Replace("'", @"\'")`

Comment: @CrazyElf , спасибо огромное, действительно работает так) Благодарю

Comment: Оформите тогда ответ, покажите там изменённый код, мне что-то лениво ответ оформлять )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

экранировать одинарные кавычки в этой строке через `.Replace`, что-то типа:

```
organizationNameRu.Replace("'", @"\'")
```